# git checkout to earlier branch doesn't change the code

Tags: git

I have 3 branches for a project repo.

master
v1
v2

Now in my local, as I am in v2, I want to go back to v1 branch. So I do

```
$git checkout v1
```

I see the output in the terminal `Switched to branch v1` and even in the atom editor, it shows that it is in branch v1. But the code doesn't go back to the `v1` state. I tried closing the editor and reopening the project but no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: what does `git diff v1 v2 -- your_file` say?

Comment: @Amadan nothing

Comment: Then your file is identical in `v1` and `v2`, and you shouldn't expect your editor contents to change.

Answer (score 1):

If u have untracked file in V2 and you are trying to checkout V1, then your untracked files would end-up in branch V1 as well.

try:

```
git add --all 
git commit -m "commits on V2"
```

while on V2 and then checkout V1